# Django: save() method in form or model?

Tags: python, django

quite a generic question here but I was curious as to when and in what cases would you use a save method in a ModelForm over the Model class itself and vice versa?

model:

```
class Model(models.Model):
...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super (Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

modelform:

```
class ModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
...
    def save(self, commit=True):
        model = super(ModelForm, self).save(commit=True)
        if commit:
            model.save()
        return model
```

Thanks!

Comment: I still consider myself relatively new to Django. I've used save in the Model class to handle special situations (automatic audit trails, extra code to automatically update some related tables, etc.) but I've never seen a save in a ModelForm. Much of my code needs to do extra work between validating the cleaned form and the actual save, so I'm not sure that a save directly in the ModelForm would make sense.

Comment: @manassehkatz Neither, but I've seen many code samples (here on SO and other sites too) which suggest using a save method as above on a ModelForm - hence my confusion!

Comment: ModelForm.save for cleaning form data, Model.save for cleaning object attributes.

Comment: You would never do **either** of these things. Neither adds any functionality over the existing base class methods. Don't override methods unless you actually change or add functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Both are overwriting the default method. Only difference is that `Model.save` is saving object attributes but `ModelForm.save` is saving form data. `ModelForm` is not just a simple `Form`. It linked to model instance. So it automatically access the fields of corresponding models.

Answer (score 0):

The difference depends on your need/usage. If you know objects will be always be created using `ModelForm` then you put your logic in `ModelForm.save` to do stuff which is required before or after saving the data. If you know the objects could be created directly as well which obviously does not go through `ModelForm` you then write your logic in `Model.save` to ensure integrirty/consistentency of data. But this does not mean that overriding `save` both on `ModelForm` and `Model` itself is bad, again there will be scenarios where you need both.